# How to style the back drop of mui modal using conditional?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I n the example below the backDrop class works only when used in the class name context I want to be able to target the back drop of the modal using classes but when I am using the commented out logic i get no color at all any idea what is the issue

```js
<Modal
      className={classes.backDrop1}
      // classes={{
      //   backDrop: `${context.modal.body === 'something' ? classes.backDrop1 :       classes.backDrop2}`,
      //   /*paper: `${context.modal.body === 'something' ? { backgroundColor:           'red' } : undefined}`,*/
      // }}
      open={context.modal.bool}
      aria-labelledby='modal-modal-title'
      aria-describedby='modal-modal-description'
    >
      {modal}
    </Modal>
```

Comment: pass props to `useStyles` like so `const classes = useStyles({ something});` & now you can use it as say `className={classes.backDrop1}`

Comment: within `createStyles` say `someText: ({ something }) => ({
      color: something ? "#67823a" : "#262626",`

Comment: I am using useStyle… !!

Comment: see codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-material-demo-forked-l3tx5?file=/demo.js. I have two `const something = true` and `const something = false`. One is commented and the other is uncommented. Now, flip that i.e. uncomment what was commented and vice-versa. See what happens. Take this approach to style your component conditionally.

Comment: My context is inside the hook cannot condition outside of the hook.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox ? I'm not quite sure I follow